# Ctrl +C shutdown for a blocking call

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Inside my loop

```
while(ros::ok())
{
// do blocking recvfrom socket
// receives data from socket
recvfrom(s, _buf, buf_size_, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen);
...

ros::spinOnce();

}
```

This code work perfectly and the ROS_INFO shows that is receives data from socket port correctly. NOTE here the incoming data is outside ros node. But when I exit using Ctrl+C. The node does not exit. The result is I have to force shutdown. This causes my port to connected. netstat shows the port is still in use. however rosnode list shows that the node has shutdown. This is likely because the code is stuck at the blocking call recvfrom. Any suggestion to overcome this ?

My question is similar to

http://answers.ros.org/question/31570/handling-sigint/

But the suggestion spinOnce didnt help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242291/ctrl-+c-shutdown-for-a-blocking-call/) by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2016-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-24**:
You probably need to set a timeout on your socket so that it exits from recvfrom when no data is received, and eventually has the opportunity to exit the main loop.

**Comment by [ROSfc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27827/rosfc/) on 2016-08-30**:
Is that the only way ? or rather the recommended way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is that the only way ? or rather the recommended way ?

I'd say that is the recommended way, as hanging in a system call is never really nice / robust (unless you use a blocking read on a suitable configured file descriptor as a timing device, or waiting for an event). You could look into `SO_RCVTIMEO` (see [Linux: is there a read or recv from socket with timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2939145)) on SO).

Another option would be using `select(..)` or Boost asio, but that would be (slightly) more involved.

> I guess I will go with timeout then. I am looking if I could use the SIGINT signal in any way

Well, at least according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3800915) (and others), `SIGINT` might not make it to `recvfrom(..)` and friends. Which could be why you are hanging in `recvfrom(..)` when you `ctrl+c` the `roslaunch` session. But I haven't verified this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1